# register_netdevice_notifier callback does not provide valid net_device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, netfilter

I work on Ubuntu kernel-mode netfilter module and need information about all network interfaces and their properties in module code. 
Inside of `init_module()` I use `register_netdevice_notifier()` for that purpose. When callback function is called I can see correct event codes like up/down and other, but it seems that third parameter `void* casted to net_device*` provides object with invalid properties. ->name is empty string, ->if index is some nonsense number etc.
I tried debug version of module on kernel 3.19 and rebuild also on 4.2. Result is the same, I cannot read properties of `net_device` relating to event.
What can be problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see from LXR, you need to call `netdev_notifier_info_to_dev` on the last parameter to get your `net_device *` (see [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/rtnetlink.c#L3412))

Comment: Thanks Joel, it is functional now.

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark this answer as correct if it solved your issue.